# How to run the examples that are bundled with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I had Flutter 0.5.1 beta with which i tried to run hello world but it did not work
So I decided to check it with dev version still it is not working, Please check following snippet for more details:

```
$~/StudioProjects/flutter/examples/hello_world$ flutter --version
Flutter 0.5.7 • channel dev • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 66091f9696 (10 days ago) • 2018-07-09 12:52:41 -0700
Engine • revision 6fe748490d
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.63.0.flutter-4c9689c1d2

$~/StudioProjects/flutter/examples/hello_world$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v0.5.7, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
$~/StudioProjects/flutter/examples/hello_world$ flutter run
Running "flutter packages get" in hello_world...                 
Because hello_world depends on flutter_test any from sdk which depends on watcher 0.9.7+8, watcher 0.9.7+8 is required.
So, because hello_world depends on watcher 0.9.7+9, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
```

When I try to run other examples, this is what happens:

```
$~/Flutter.0.5.7/examples/catalog$ flutter run
Running "flutter packages get" in catalog...                 0.5s
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       1.2s
Resolving dependencies...                                    1.8s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...                          16.3s
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                  0.9s
D/        ( 7730): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdc2a9bc0, tid 7750
D/EGL_emulation( 7730): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe6abd0a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xdc2ff790)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...         3.3s

  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Android SDK built for x86 is available at: http://X.X.X.X:XXXX/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
```

[image: running in emulator]

Comment: Try `flutter channel beta` and then `flutter packages get` again.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried this
flutter channel beta > flutter run (hello world) > It shows black screen with hello world text in center, which is fine, after this I tried to run catalog example but I see same thing as shown in screenshot.

Comment: platform_channel, platform_view seems to work with beta channel

Comment: flutter_gallery works too with beta channel :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments on the question the examples might not work in cases when the Flutter distribution is not updated or when you are on channel other then beta(stable or canary?) 
you can execute this commands and see if it works or not.

```
flutter channel beta #switch to beta channel
flutter packages get #update the packages?
```